# Doxygen complains about entities in excluded files not being documented

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen 1.8.11 gives the following warning:

```
/home/meir/Dropbox/CurrentWork/Development/SearchLib/core/util/reflection/struct_2_stream.h:9: warning: Compound slb::core::util::print_visitor is not documented.
```

However, the configuration file is located in `/home/meir/Dropbox/CurrentWork/Development/SearchLib/` and has the following line:

```
EXCLUDE                = temp/ projects/ core/util/outside/ core/util/graphics/colors/ core/util/reflection/ symbols.cpp
```

Specifically, `core/util/reflection/` is excluded. So, why does `Doxygen` insist that an entity in `core/util/reflection/struct_2_stream.h` be documented?

Comment: Where are you running it from? These paths are relative to cwd for Doxygen.

Comment: From `/home/meir/Dropbox/CurrentWork/Development/SearchLib/`